# GuideLine don't work in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-constraintlayout

I want to creat a dialogFragment like this:

[image]

Actually I got this on my phone:

[image]

button1 is covered by button2. It looks like the guideLine does not work.
If textView is long enough, it works well. But if textView is short, the problem will happen. How can i fix the problem.

my dialog xml is :

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="32dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dialog Message"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_button_positive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Positive"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceButton"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dialog_message" />

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_button_negative"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Negative"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceButton"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dialog_message" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Guideline has a bug with dialogs or any screen that's not full screen. I have an activity that is full screen on mobile, but a dialog on a tablet, and a view that relies on `Guideline` just disappeared.

As [yao liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4922713/yao-liu) said before, using `getDialog().getWindow().setLayout()` on a dialog fragment, or just `getWindow().setLayout(...)` on `onStart()` works and shows that view.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the guideline, you can use `Chains` instead.
Try this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="32dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dialog Message"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_button_positive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Positive"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/dialog_button_negative"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dialog_message" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_button_negative"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Negative"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/dialog_button_positive"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dialog_message" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In case you are not familiar with chains, here is a [small tutorial](https://constraintlayout.github.io/basics/create_chains.html)

Comment: I did as your answer, but the second button displayed incomplete.I solve the  problem by call setLayout. So  i add `getDialog().getWindow().setLayout()` in method `onStart()`

Comment: Chains can't replace Guidline for everything so this doesn't necessarily answer the question for other people that end up here.

Comment: I never said chains replace guidelines for everything, they are two different things, and obviously it's not an accepted answer.